# File transfer with linux pc through mobile hotspot

Tags: applications, file-transfer, wifi-hotspot

How do I  transfer files with a PC running Linux (Ubuntu) via the mobile hotspot (not through wifi)? (Perhaps with another third-party application)

Comment: Does the pc have wifi functionality? Then yes, just connect to your Hotspot and transfer with any networking app. I suggest FTP or SMB.

Answer (score 2):

The set up of file transfer between **Android device and Linux PC** is similar to  Windows and can be achieved in a variety of ways.

I created  simple tutorial illustrating the simplest way to do it (without need for extra tricky terminal commands in Linux, or installing additional packages)

**Requirements:**

- Mobile hotspot
- Linux PC (running any linux distro eg Ubuntu, Mint, Kali etc but for this tutorial I used Zorin OS)
  with **Wi-Fi functionality**
- Android file explorer capable of **FTP/SMB/SFTP** protocols (I used [ES explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) for this task)

**Instructions**

1. Connect Linux PC to hotpsot.
2. Open ES File explorer and go to Networks >> Remote Manager (FTP protocol) and turn on service. See screenshot.

[image: Remote manager]

3. Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+T and type `ifconfig` (just to be sure the PC was assigned a correct IP by the DHCP) The dhcp range is  `192.168.43.xxx`

Using File manager from Unity Launcher head to Connect to server under Other Locations and input FTP server details and port number (ftp//192.168.43.1:3721/)

[image: Connecting to server]

Enter login details or leave as anonymous:

[image: Login]

From now you can access files in your android device on Linux PC, and can perform various actions e.g copy,paste etc (some names hidden for other reasons)

[image: File browsing]

[image: FTP folder]

Comment: Will this method let me write on the SD card from the PC?

Comment: @becko Sure it does! the user has rw permissions by default, to prevent unathourised access you may set password authentication

Answer (score 0):

There are many FTP clients for android in play store, you can use that to create a FTP serever on phone, and access the server from computer,