# Transfer files from Nexus 5 to PC

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, file-transfer

I recently got a new phone and want to back up the files from my old phone (Nexus 5) before passing it on to a family member.

Using MTP connected to a Windows 10 PC the transfer is unbearably slow (around 10-20 seconds per file, even though a file may only be a few kB). Using MTP connected to a Mac using Android File Transfer is a lot faster, however the app crashes, freezes or gives an error after a minute or two and stops transferring files.

Is there a better way to transfer files, or a solution to the slow transfer speeds on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried with another wire or with ADB?

Comment: And have you checked with our [file-transfer tag-wiki](/tags/file-transfer/info) and the [answered questions using this tag](/search?q=[file-transfer]+answers%3A1) yet? Bet you'll find your answer there :) And yes, MTP is slow as hell – which is one of the reasons I never use it. Fastest would be using [ADB](/tags/adb/info) and e.g. a [file manager supporting that](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947) (*Droid Explorer* by our community member Ryan Conrad is probably a good choice on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

When there are many files to be transferred, and small ones at that, this has been reported:

[Share Via http](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MarcosDiez.shareviahttp) is an *open source* app worth considering. It's handy to share with other mobile devices as well

Alternatively, you can consider other [File Sync](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync) apps from the curated list maintained by Izzy

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my lists, beeshyams (I just fixed the link to directly point to what you've named). While having posted my own answer already (going ADB and pull), in context of your answer (going app and push) [File manager supporting all local file systems & LAN](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156) might also be worth a look. Especially with Windows, they could directly access the PC via SMB/CIFS, eg. [AndroXplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.adisasta.androxplorer).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a different file transfer protocol, preferably SMB or similar, to transfer the files. Somehow, MTP is buggy because speeds get significantly lower when transferring small files and takes a while to peak again.

Try file transfer apps such as ES explorer, Sambadroid, etc (I have used these with no speed issues). Even over Wi-Fi, you still get consistent transfer speeds (1-2 MB/s)

I also have written another post to achieve this [using Sambadroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/170986/209414). The same can also be achieved using the former [app as outline here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143115/file-transfer-with-linux-pc-through-mobile-hotspot) (it is the same for Windows).

Comment: I remember from my Windows days, using TeraCopy for reliable file transfers and the ability to pause/resume, somehow i felt, it resulted in faster data transfer, just thought i would mention the tool for someone using this way.

Answer (score 1):

The probably fastest solution would be using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) (check with our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info) for some background and hints for setup). To ease things up (and not gluing you to the command line), you could use a [file manager supporting ADB](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947). As you're being on Windows, my recommendation for that part would be [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer), written and maintained by our community member [Ryan Conrad](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/1951/ryan-conrad).

You might consider the effort needed for an initial setup on Windows a bit much. But if you check with above linked ADB tag-wiki for what you'll be able to do with ADB (and with *Droid Explorer,* not to forget) beside the simple file-transfer task, I'll bet you'll find it worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another USB cord ? or if your laptop has a USB 3.0 port, use that instead.  If its still the same, try using file Transfer apps from the 
 Play Store like **ShareIT**,  **Xender** or **Snappea** etc.